# Getting errors on executing GRASS v.distance tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have 2 shapefiles. One is a route and another one are the points along this route. I need to get the distance along the route.
When I try to execute GRASS v.distance algorithm I get these errors:

```
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows

ERROR: Unable to open file 'C:/Users/РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_UCTeOT/d5f8dd391daf4b1ba9499140012d4380/crs.prj' for reading

ERROR: OGR layer <Ruby> not found

ERROR: Unable to open vector map <vector_61ac84296e5103>

ERROR: Vector map <output85a6234dfd7d40cba1621e564634d1ba> not found

ERROR: Key column <> not found

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/Пользователь/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_UCTeOT/12f187556e0141bbbb0845767051974b/output.gpkg
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Could anyone suggest what does it want?
QGIS version
3.16.14-Hannover

Comment: Not a solution, but I'd like to clarify that `v.distance` does not solve the problem of distances along a line. It adds to each of the points a distance **to** the line. I think you should be looking for Linear Referencing.

Comment: Are you sure? V.distance has several options including distance along. I watched this and it looks like its what I need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzCrUll0gCI&t=305s

Comment: You are right! Sorry for misleading. The to_along option will add values to the points layer indicating the distance **along the line** for the connector from each point to the line

Answer (score 1):

To test, I grabbed a line segment from a streams network, then digitized a few points near the line.
Here's what I got running:

```
v.distance from=pts to=a_line output=connectors upload=to_along column=to_along
```

[image: V.distance using to_along]

Then, zooming in, you can see the connector lines from each point to the line:

[image: Zoom in]

HTH, micha

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I am looking for. Just don't understand the reason for errors I have

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what commands you are running, what your input layers are, and what error you're getting? What is "Ruby" in the error message above?

Comment: So the input layers are: 1. Shapefile with route, which is called "Ruby" 2. Shpfile with boulders(points) along this route. Points have attrubutes: name, easting, northing, KP. KP column is empty - there I want to have distance along . So I launch Grass v.distance tool,  choose "from vector map" my boulders, "to vector map" - my route. Parameters I set to_along. Column name where values will be uploaded I set as KP.  And then I press run and have those errors  and new empty file which is called "nearest"

Comment: Can you load both shapefiles into QGIS? Do you know what coordinate projections they are in? (Maybe you already know, but you must have all components of the shapefile: *.shp, *.shx, *.dbf and *.prj for both the route and the points)

Comment: They both in the project. Projection EPSG 25831.

Comment: This line in your error message:

`ERROR: Unable to open file 'C:/Users/РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_UCTeOT/d5f8dd391daf4b1ba9499140012d4380/crs.prj' for reading`

makes me suspicous that something is wrong with the original shp files. Does each have a `*.prj` component??

Comment: That error already gone. It was because the User was in russian language. I renamed it.  They both have prj. I tried to create new shp files with projection of course - just a point and a line. And had the same errors. I have a feeling its maybe something with grass path variables, not sure. Did you setup GRASS in system path variable?

Comment: Can you possibly share the Ruby and boulders shapefiles?

I could then show a complete workflow using GRASS GIS directly, without the QGIS Processing toolbox in the middle.

Comment: The thing is I need to do it in QGIS. Because its just one of the several calculations I need to do in one go. In reality I have hundreds of boulders and around 15 routes. Also I have poligons along the routes. So the task is to get a table with arguments: Boulders ID, KP to nearest route, the poligon where the boulder is falling to. I was going to use QGIS graphical modeller for this.

Comment: I don't know about which polygon the boulder will fall to. But if I had a line shapefile with all 15 routes, and a point shapefile of all hundreds of boulders, I could show how to add the distance along the nearest route (Is that what KP means??)  for the boulders.
BTW, QGIS can read GRASS data layers directly, and GRASS can export back to either shapefile or geopackage, so there's no problem to integrate into a QGIS model.

Comment: Thanks Micha, I also have options to do part of task in extra packages, but the aim is to do this task in "one click" in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

The path

`C:/Users/РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ/...`

looks potentially problematic. Can you try with a user account that does not contain any special characters?

Comment: Just tried, the 1st  error gone. The rest errors still there:

Answer (score 0):

The KP Find plugin does exactly this, it can do geodetic or Cartesian distances, as well. It can be found in the repository; the caveat is that it only works with projected coordinate systems.

Comment: Hello, thanks for comment! Kp find is good, but i can't use the result of the plug-in in graphical modeler for further calculations,  can I? Anyway , solved the problem by implementing linelocatepoint function in my script

Comment: No, that is not currently possible. But this is good feedback, maybe in the future the option can be added.